# Access to path %userprofile%\AppData\Local is denied

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim mspasss As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
    Dim Ressource1() As Byte = My.Resources.mspass
    FileOpen(1, mspasss, OpenMode.Binary)
    FilePut(1, Ressource1)
```

returns Access to %userprofile%\AppData\Local is denied
 i dunno what else to do please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to write to a directory. Maybe you want something like this:

```
Dim mspasss As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
mspasss = System.Io.Path.Combine(mspasss, "someFile.dat")
Dim Ressource1() As Byte = My.Resources.mspass
FileOpen(1, mspasss, OpenMode.Binary)
FilePut(1, Ressource1)
```

This makes the path to %userprofile%\AppData\Local\someFile.dat